# What is the meaning of this C# code and how do I use it?

Tags: c#

```
public int this[int x, int y]
{
   get { return (x + y); }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) that accepts two integers. You can think of it as similar to a two dimensional array, except that the result is calculated on the fly instead of being stored.

It allows you to write `int result = foo[a, b];`

Answer (score 1):

It is an indexer, and that code is probably incorrect. You would normally see:

```
public int this[int x, int y]
{
    get { return (x * ColSize + y); }
}
```

---

```
class TheMatrix<T>
{
    private int _rows, _cols;
    private T[] _data;
    public TheMatrix(int rows, int cols)
    {
        _rows = rows;
        _cols = cols;
        _data = new T[_rows * _cols];
    }

    T this[int r, int c]
    {
        get { return _data[r * _cols + c]; }
        set { _data[r * _cols + c] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: i  am agree with you but show me to call your function and mine both.